# Vutify - how to reduce size of tab headers?

Tags: vuetify.js

I am using `v-tabs` in my app but when running on mobile they take up too much space. If I could reduce the padding around the text, all the tabs would fit without using the arrows.[image: image of tabs]

I have tried all sorts of padding and margin changes in the class for the tabs without success.

[Vuetify playground here](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

```
 <template>
  <v-sheet>
    <v-row no-gutters>
      <v-col>
        <v-tabs
          class="ma-n3 pa-n2"
          bg-color="blue-lighten-4"
          center-active
          color="blue"
          show-arrows
          stacked
        >
          <v-tab value="calendar"
            ><v-icon icon="mdiCalendarMonth" /> Rides</v-tab
          >
          <v-tab value="newRide"> <v-icon icon="mdiBike" /> New</v-tab>
          <v-tab value="routes"> <v-icon icon="mdiMap" /> Routes</v-tab>
          <v-tab value="coffee"> <v-icon icon="mdiCoffee" /> Coffee</v-tab>
          <v-tab value="account">
            <v-icon icon="mdiAccountEdit" /> Account</v-tab
          >
          <v-tab value="help"> <v-icon icon="mdiHelp" /> Help</v-tab>
          <v-tab value="exit"> <v-icon icon="mdiDoorOpen" /> Exit</v-tab>
        </v-tabs>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-sheet>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  const msg = ref('Hello World!')
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can change tab width through Vue props, you have to override the CSS. Note that there is a `min-width` of 90px on the tab buttons that you'll probably want to reduce along with the padding:

```css
  .v-btn--stacked.v-tab.v-btn {
    padding: 0 4px;
    min-width: 70px;
  }
```

I'd probably add the [`grow`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-tabs/#props-grow) prop of v-tabs to make it look less wonky on large displays.

---

Note that using negative margins (the `ma-n3` class) does not remove size, but lets the element's content overlap its box. It's probably not what you want to do. Instead, use the v-tabs [`:height`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-tabs/#props-height) prop to reduce overall height:

```html
  <v-tabs
    height="60px"
    ...
```

---

Have a look at the [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: I have now changed `min-width` to `20vw` (for 5 tabss) so the screen width is filled completely.